# The PC goes to UEFI every time I reboot the PC

Tags: uefi

Whenever I simply turn off the PC a proper Ubuntu boot screen shows up where I can choose between Ubuntu, Windows and the UEFI setting, but each time I try rebooting it I get kicked to the BIOS and all the boot settings are gone and only Windows gets loaded. If I want to access Ubuntu again I have to reload the PC again through Windows and set Ubuntu as a boot option again. It's not that big of a deal, but it's extremely annoying. Any ideas as to why this keeps happening?
I'm using the latest version of both Ubuntu and Windows. To install the former, I burned the iso file on a flash drive, created partitions for it on my SSD (Windows is installed on my HDD) and then installed it. The problem only occurs on Linux, everything works fine if I reboot from Windows.

Comment: Can you put a bit more information in? Dual boot - presumably windows 10/11 and Ubuntu - which version? And does this happen when you reboot from either os or just one?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe the steps you used to install Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: @Bodo It is done.

Comment: Did you create partitions before running the installation or as part of the installation? Add Details about your partitions. What options did you select during the installation?

Comment: @Bodo Yes, I created partitions for Linux and it's swap area. During installation I didn't choose to install it alongside Windows and went to the advanced settings, where I set the partitions as what they should be.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information to the question. Especially as you chose the advanced settings, all details might be important. What type of partition table, what partitions did you create, what flags did you set? What partitions does your HDD have? Did you get any questions about installing GRUB2?